# Python file naming

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, and I have this script based off of this:

github/whiteShtef/LiteScraper

It is being used to scrape images and gifs from http://ifunny.co

The problem is, the script saves images in seperate folders.

This is the code for naming folders:

```
    foldername=self.url[7:]
    foldername=foldername.split("/")[0]

    extension=time.strftime("iFunny")+"-"+time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "-" + time.strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss")
```

It will do the foldername iFunny with a timestamp after it.

What I need is that it can save all downloads to the folder "images"

I have tried making it simply save to the folder "images", but the problem is as it scrapes different pages the images get the same name, and they overwrite eachother.

For example if it scrapes page 1, it will download the images from it (im pretty sure its 10 images/gifs per page) and it will name them 1, 2, 3, 4 ect...

Then it scrapes page 2 and names them 1, 2, 3, 4 ect... and overwrites the old images from page 1.

This is the full code:

```
import os
import time
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

#todo: char support for Windows
#deal with triple backslash filter
#recursive parser option


class LiteScraper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.lastStartTag="No-Tag"
        self.lastAttributes=[]
        self.lastImgUrl=""
        self.Data=[]
        self.acceptedTags=["div","p","h","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","ul","li","a","img"]
        self.counter=0
        self.url=""


        self.SAVE_DIR=""
        self.Headers=["User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"]

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):
        #print("Encountered a START tag:",tag)
        self.lastStartTag=tag
        self.lastAttributes=attrs #unnecesarry, might come in hany

        if self.lastStartTag=="img":
            attrs=self.lastAttributes

            for attribute in attrs:
                if attribute[0]=="src":
                    self.lastImgUrl=attribute[1]
                    print(attribute[1])

                    #Allow GIF from iFunny to download
                    for attribute in attrs:
                        if attribute[0]=="data-gif":
                            self.lastImgUrl=attribute[1]
                            print(attribute[1])
                            #End Gif Code

            self.handle_picture(self.lastImgUrl)

    def handle_endtag(self,tag):
        #print("Encountered a END tag:",tag)
        pass

    def handle_data(self,data):
        data=data.replace("\n"," ")
        data=data.replace("\t"," ")
        data=data.replace("\r"," ")
        if self.lastStartTag in self.acceptedTags:
            if not data.isspace():
                print("Encountered some data:",data)
                self.Data.append(data)

        else:
            print("Encountered filtered data.") #Debug

    def handle_picture(self,url):
        print("Bumped into a picture. Downloading it now.")
        self.counter+=1
        if url[:2]=="//":
            url="http:"+url

        extension=url.split(".")
        extension="."+extension[-1]

        try:
            req=urllib.request.Request(url)
            req.add_header(self.Headers[0],self.Headers[1])
            response=urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10)
            picdata=response.read()
            file=open(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics/"+str(self.counter)+extension,"wb")
            file.write(picdata)
            file.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Something went wrong, sorry.")


    def start(self,url):
        self.url=url
        self.checkSaveDir()

        try: #wrapped in exception - if there is a problem with url/server
            req=urllib.request.Request(url)
            req.add_header(self.Headers[0],self.Headers[1])
            response=urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=10)
            siteData=response.read().decode("utf-8")
            self.feed(siteData)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        self.__init__()  #resets the parser/scraper for serial parsing/scraping
        print("Done!")

    def checkSaveDir(self):
        #----windows support
        if os.name=="nt":
            container="\ "
            path=os.path.normpath(__file__)
            path=path.split(container[0])
            path=container[0].join(path[:len(path)-1])
            path=path.split(container[0])
            path="/".join(path)
        #no more windows support! :P
        #for some reason, os.normpath returns path with backslashes
        #on windows, so they had to be supstituted with fowardslashes.

        else:
            path=os.path.normpath(__file__)
            path=path.split("/")
            path="/".join(path[:len(path)-1])

        foldername=self.url[7:]
        foldername=foldername.split("/")[0]

        extension=time.strftime("iFunny")+"-"+time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "-" + time.strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss")

        self.SAVE_DIR=path+"/"+foldername+"-"+extension


        if not os.path.exists(self.SAVE_DIR):
            os.makedirs(self.SAVE_DIR)

        if not os.path.exists(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics"):
            os.makedirs(self.SAVE_DIR+"/pics")

        print(self.SAVE_DIR)
```

Im not exactly sure what to do here, any help would be great!

Comment: Could you copy the code for naming images here?  It sounds like you just want to name them sequentially.

Comment: Hey Anon, welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple things to help you use the site more effectively. First, please make sure to include the code directly in your question instead of posting it on an external service such as Pastebin. Secondly, please make sure that the exact issue you're having is clear. I'm not entirely sure what the exact problem is, but I'm guessing that you do _not_ want it to overwrite previously downloaded images which is what it's doing now? Be sure to stop by the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information on how to use the site! Happy asking!

Comment: At present, this really isn't ideal, as a question. Something that's written as a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) focusing on a very specific problem (with code unnecessary to reproduce that problem factored out) is going to get a much better response. There should be no need for the complexity of a HTML parser for a question that's focused on filename generation. See also http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

(After you remove the section for timestamp)
Looks like self.counter is the value that determines the file name.  Its set to zero when a LiteScraper object is created.  If you reuse the LiteScraper object when you move to the next page, it should continue to count instead of starting back at zero.

Instead call start() again on the same object.  like this:

```
scraper = LiteScraper()
scraper.start(<url/page1>) #images 1, 2, 3, & 4 are created
scraper.start(<url/page2>) #images 5, 6, 7, etc.
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. The site I am scraping does not exactly have "pages", I am scraping like this http://pastebin.com/53h7GmQJ

Comment: Delete this section: `+"-"+time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "-" + time.strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss")`.  self.count is not getting reset if the object is reused, so it should continue counting in that case.